# How to get a directory listing in python on a web browser?

Tags: python, webserver

I have a web server running, listening on port 7000. So when I do a GET request through a browser i.e. 127.0.0.1:7000/ I need the contents of that directory to be listed, just the way the command
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on terminal responds. How do I do this using the "os" module?

```
    from socket import *
    import os
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)     #create a socket

    #Prepare server socket
    serverPort = 7000
    serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1)

    while True:
        print 'Ready to serve . . .'
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()  #create socket for client
        try:
            message =connectionSocket.recv(1024)   #receive message from client
            print message
            filename = message.split()[1]
            f = open(filename[1:])
            outputdata =f.read()                
            #Send contents of the requested file to the client
            for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
                connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
            connectionSocket.close()
            print 'File Received'
        except IOError:
            connectionSocket.send('\n404 File Not Found\n')
            connectionSocket.close()
    serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: what server are you running? are you using [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) module?

Comment: No, I am only using socket and os module. I wanted to do it without the SimpleHTTPServer module. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I pasted the code above. I'm trying to figure out a way, that when a GET request for / is made the directory listing should be served on the browser. so the "outputdata" in this case would just pick "/" and return directory listing ideally.